# Cleaner than sleep infinity

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When starting Docking containers, it is common to use `sleep infinity` or `tail -f /dev/null` to keep them up. The drawback is that these methods take a while when you want to stop the container.

Is there are cleaner way to do this? I am wondering if someone has a nice solution for this already.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I updated the question in case it was not clear. Basically I am trying to find a cleaner way to keep the containers up. I suppose there must be an interruptible bash script with better properties than sleep infinity